# How would I go about putting this boolean expression into sum of two products form?

Tags: boolean-logic, karnaugh-map

So I started with xy'+x'y+xz+y'z

I used a Kmap and ended up with the equvalent solution

z+x'y+xy'

From here I need to make this into a sum of two products and take the complement of it to get the solution I need.

But I see no way to turn this into a sum of two products

I can use the distributive law and end up with (z+x')(z+y)+xy'

But I'm pretty sure this is not sum of two products, at least not in the sense my book was showing me

Comment: The inverse of the expression is a sum of two products `x'y'z' + xyz'`.

Comment: Not possible - unless you invert the result of a sum of two products

Comment: Would `(x + y)(xy)' + (x + y')z` be considered valid?

Answer (score -1):

Boolean Expression (given):

```
xy'+x'y+xz+y'z
```

Kmap:

```
xy\z 0 1
00   0 1   
01   1 1
11   0 1
10   1 1
```

Boolean Expression in Product of Two Sums Form (as requested):

```
(x + y + z)(x' + y' + z)
```